# F# yield! (yieldbang) operator

Tags: f#, yield

I am learning F# at the moment but I'm having a hard time understanding this:

```
let allPrimes =
let rec allPrimes' n = 
    seq {
        if isPrime n then
            yield n
        yield! allPrimes' (n + 1) }
allPrimes' 2
```

I am not able to figure out what the `yield!` operator exactly does even though I've read other simpler examples and it seems `yield!` returns an inner sequence.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The yield bang operator merges the sub sequence produced by the called sequence expressions into the final sequence. Or in simpler words: it "flattens" the returned sequence to include the elements of the sub sequence in the final sequence.

For your example: Without the yield bang operator you would get something like

```
{ prime1 { prime2 { prime3 .... }}}
```

with the yield bang operator you get

```
{ prime1 prime2 prime3 ... }
```

where each `{` denotes a new sequence.

---

> **Side note**: The actual result from my first example would even include more sequences, as it would return sequences only containing sequences as the prime is only returned if `n is prime`.

Comment: I assume this means that yield! only takes a sequences/other enumerables as argument?